# Parse a simple json string, got after posting body to url

Tags: android

I know its a bit silly question, but as i am new to android and i have no idea about json parsing, i have to ask this.
I have to parse this kind of string

```
{"message":"Success","status":"1"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic parsing is like this:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(myString);
String message = jobj.getString("message");
String status = jobj.getString("status");
```

More to read:

- [Android JSON docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)
- [JSON format docs](http://www.json.org/)